# How can we deploy custom My Domain name via metadata API?

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx-cli, mydomain

Is there a way to deploy custom `My Domain` in `Metadata API` deployment using `SFDX CLI`?

Comment: Are you asking about Domain or my domain?

Comment: I'm looking to deploy `My Domain` via CLI/Metadata API.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Domains are single-use items globally, so there's no point in having a Metadata API call for this. This feature cannot normally be disabled or reassigned to a new org without intervention from support.

Comment: But I can go into `Setup > My Domains` and change to a new domain. I was hoping we can change/deploy new my domain name via CLI.

Comment: @VarunC Oh. New feature, then. Still, you're required to take several actions before you can use the domain, so a deployment doesn't make sense. You have to check availability, and ideally perform testing first.

Comment: Yes i know, though I'm good with steps, if there will be any :-) I would hope to get an error back if it is duplicate, similar to when we create new users in test/scratch orgs with possible duplicate usernames. I'm been searching docs to see if there is any Metadata specific to My Domain name deployment, but sadly none found so far.

Comment: @sfdcfox right now when I install the package I lost the assignment to a domain. Do you have any idea how to keep the assignment?